# Imprimir imagenes de diferentes tamaños en wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, impresión

Necesito imprimir imágenes de diferentes tamaños(4x6, 5x7 y 6x8) pulgadas, el problema es que no logro hacer que la impresora corte los papeles correctamente, ya que siempre corta al tamaño de las preferencias de impresión. Estás preferencias las puedo cambiar fácilmente con PrintDialog Clase y sus propiedades pero solo me aplica a la primera imagen, es decir, que agrego a una cola de impresion 2 imagenes las primera 6x8 y la segunda 4x6 las dos cortarán el tamaño del papel a 6x8 como la primera opción.

```
    static void Test(int width, int height)//Pulgadas
    {
        var dialog = new PrintDialog()
        {
            PrintQueue = new PrintServer().GetPrintQueue("MITSUBISHI CPD90D")
        };
        var queue = dialog.PrintQueue;
        var printTicket = queue.DefaultPrintTicket;
        printTicket.PageMediaSize = new PageMediaSize(width * 96, height * 96);
        printTicket.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Portrait;
        BitmapImage photo = GetPhoto();

        bool isPortrait = photo.Width < photo.Height;

        double photoScale = Math.Max(photo.Width / (width * 96), photo.Height / (height * 96));
        var resultWidth = photo.Width / photoScale;
        var resultHeight = photo.Height / photoScale;

        DrawingVisual visual = new DrawingVisual();
        var render = visual.RenderOpen();
        render.PushTransform(new RotateTransform(isPortrait ? 0 : 90));
        render.DrawImage(photo, new Rect { Width = resultWidth, Height = resultHeight, X = 0, Y = 0 });
        render.Close();

        queue.CurrentJobSettings.Description = "Test";
        XpsDocumentWriter xpsDocumentWriter = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(queue);
        xpsDocumentWriter.Write(visual, printTicket);
    }
```

Tambien tengo problemas para ajustar la imagen, es decir que ocupe toda el area de impresion.

`printDialog.PrintQueue.GetPrintCapabilitiesAsXml()` me retorna la siguiente información: [printer capabilities file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1h8MyTlkuuLtFieH4C8BCGpsYYq_wigqJ)

Comment: nunca he realizado algo como eso, pero siguiendo la logica si tienes una cola de impresion cada vez que se imprima una imagen debes limpiar las variables que mandaste a imprimir y volver a cargarlas con las nuevas medidas, asi sucesivamente hasta terminar la cola.

Comment: Imaginate que llamo la funcion dentro de un ciclo cambiando los parametros `width` y `height` lo esperado es que cambie el tamaño de la impresión, pero siempre imprimira el papel del tamaño de la primera iteración.

Comment: y si mandas a imprimir una por una con diferentes medidas si salen correctamente? desde donde llamas a tu metodo test(); pega tu codigo

Comment: Ni una por una el problema está en que no puedo cambiar las preferencias mas de una vez

Comment: y revisaste en la pagina de la impresora si existe alguna SDK que ayude a solucionar tu problemas.

Comment: claro, me he tratado de contactar con el soporte y nada